# How can I align the College Scorecard population totals to those that are derived from IPEDS?

Tags: collegescorecard, population

According to the scorecard dictionary, the undergraduate totals are defined as "the number of degree/certificate-seeking undergraduates enrolled in the fall, as reported in the IPEDS Fall Enrollment component.

In the IPEDS raw data (https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/DataFiles.aspx?goToReportId=7), one gets a more finite breakdown of enrollment by year. I have synthesized the total undergrad population by combining the full-time and part-time undergraduate men and women total counts (efrace15/efrace15), but this number does not always seem to match the College Scorecard Data.

I'd love to figure out how my totals can match for replication purposes!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer.

I have previously matched the undergraduate total for degree/certificate-seeking undergraduates enrolled in the fall (UGDS) variable in Scorecard by checking the following 3 under Fall Enrollment/ Gender,attendance, and level of student:

First time
Transfer-ins
Continuing

I have used the IPEDS data center to choose my variables.

https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/SelectVariables.aspx

Hope this helps.